# Windows Forms - Enter keypress activates submit button?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I capture enter keypresses anywhere on my form and force it to fire the submit button event?

Comment: So why don't you press the AcceptButton property on Matt Hamilton's answer?

Comment: use 'this.Form.DefaultButton = MyButton.UniqueID;'

Answer (score 214):

If you set your `Form`'s `AcceptButton` property to one of the `Button`s on the `Form`, you'll get that behaviour by default.

Otherwise, set the `KeyPreview` property to `true` on the `Form` and handle its `KeyDown` event. You can check for the `Enter` key and take the necessary action.

Comment: and don't forget about CancelButton for handling Escape keypress

Comment: e.g., If you have a button called `submitButton`, then you need put `this.AcceptButton = submitButton` into your form's constructor.

Comment: Additionally: You can use the same idea with the escape key, `this.CancelButton = myCancelButton`.

Answer (score 34):

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        button.PerformClick();
}
```

Answer (score 25):

You can designate a button as the "AcceptButton" in the Form's properties and that will catch any "Enter" keypresses on the form and route them to that control.

See [How to: Designate a Windows Forms Button as the Accept Button Using the Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/designate-a-wf-button-as-the-accept-button-using-the-designer) and note the few exceptions it outlines (multi-line text-boxes, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the link, those exceptions where holding me up.

Comment: This link appears to have died.

Answer (score 11):

As previously stated, set your form's *AcceptButton* property to one of its buttons AND set the *DialogResult* property for that button to *DialogResult.OK*, in order for the caller to know if the dialog was accepted or dismissed.

Answer (score 9):

You can subscribe to the `KeyUp` event of the `TextBox`.

```
private void txtInput_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
       DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for. I have button dialogresult set to OK and didn't want to write unnecesary code for ENTER to work!

Answer (score 2):

The Form has a [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property that you can use to intercept the keypress.

Answer (score 2):

Set the KeyPreview attribute on your form to True, then use the KeyPress event at your form level to detect the Enter key. On detection call whatever code you would have for the "submit" button.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
this.Form.DefaultButton = MyButton.UniqueID;
```

**Put your button id in place of 'MyButton'.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "Return")
  { 
      //do something
  }
```